# Omnifaces <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"/> not working

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, omnifaces, deltaspike

I have a .war web app with PrimeFaces 6.2 + OmniFaces 2.6.9 + DeltaSpike JSF module 1.8.2. 
I have a p:selectOneMenu with omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter and the bean is deltaspike @ViewAccessScoped. The selectItems list is in the bean. I have the correct toString() implementation in the entity but
The converter is not working it always gives the same exception

> javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert 1 of type class
>   java.lang.Integer to class
>   ar.com.eden.semestre.entities.QaEstadosSemestres

Is omnifaces converter works with ViewAccessScope bean?

```html
<p:selectOneMenu id="txtEstado" 
   requiredMessage="Debe ingresar un estado" 
   required="true" 
   value="#{semestreBean.semestre.estado}">
   <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"/> 
   <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Seleccione un estado"/>
   <f:selectItems value="#{semestreBean.estadosLov}" var="e" itemLabel="#{e.nombre}" itemValue="#{e.id}"/> 
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

What can be wrong?
 Thanks.

Comment: By the way, it is running on Jboss 7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a mistake in the code, instead of returning the object i was returning the id in the itemValue property of the selectItems tag.

Comment: Then mark this answer as the correct one since you solved your own question.